# Compare and merge array of objects in Javascript if first object does not contain objects from second array

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I want to compare and add elements from the second array into the first whichever objects or nested objects are not present in the first array of objects.

There is a nested array of objects of Location which we also have to check for each object and we can compare using the `_id` key.

I tried with the filter method but I can only achieve removing the elements which are not matched.

```js
let obj1 = [
    {
      "_id": "63eb2c20fd30492730e203bb",
      "name": "name 01",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [],
      "code": "888888"
    },
    {
      "_id": "638482b90b6d64eccee23be7",
      "name": "name 02",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 03",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "+1 845566 556",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd64212a8"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 04",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd6464789"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 05",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd65843a8"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

let obj2=[
    {
      "_id": "63eb2c20fd30492730e203bb",
      "name": "name 01",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [],
      "code": "888888"
    },
    {
      "_id": "638482b90b6d64eccee23be7",
      "name": "name 02",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 03",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "+1 845566 556",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd64212a8"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 08",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153ferg52a8"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "63eb2c20hijkl920e203bb",
      "name": "name 10",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [],
      "code": "888888"
    }
  ]
```

We can see that in obj2 there is one child object which is not present and one object which is not present in obj1.
My Trial:
It is merging the objects, but duplicating the nested objects, which i want to filter

```js
function mergeDeep(target, source) {
  const isObject = (obj) => obj && typeof obj === 'object';

  if (!isObject(target) || !isObject(source)) {
    return source;
  }
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    const targetValue = target[key];
    const sourceValue = source[key];

    if (Array.isArray(targetValue) && Array.isArray(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = targetValue.concat(sourceValue);
    } else if (isObject(targetValue) && isObject(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = mergeDeep(Object.assign({}, targetValue), sourceValue);
    } else {
      target[key] = sourceValue;
    }
  });
  return target;
}
```

Expected Output:

```js
let output = [
    {
      "_id": "63eb2c20fd30492730e203bb",
      "name": "name 01",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [],
      "code": "888888"
    },
    {
      "_id": "638482b90b6d64eccee23be7",
      "name": "name 02",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 03",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "+1 845566 556",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd64212a8"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 04",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd6464789"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 05",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153cecd65843a8"
        },
        {
          "primaryContact": {
            "name": "name 08",
            "designation": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
            "isBilling": true
          },
          "_id": "638484359f153ferg52a8"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "63eb2c20hijkl920e203bb",
      "name": "name 10",
      "isActive": true,
      "locations": [],
      "code": "888888"
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Please add the code of your attempt so it shows what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you detect arrays, add some logic to read the `_id` properties of the objects in the concatenated array: collect these objects and key them by `_id` in an object (so the `_id` is guaranteed to become unique). Then get the values of that object again:

```js
function mergeDeep(target, source) {
  const isObject = (obj) => obj && typeof obj === 'object';

  if (!isObject(target) || !isObject(source)) {
    return source;
  }
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    const targetValue = target[key];
    const sourceValue = source[key];

    if (Array.isArray(targetValue) && Array.isArray(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = targetValue.concat(sourceValue);
      // Add this:
      if (target[key][0]?._id) {
        target[key] = Object.values(
          Object.fromEntries(target[key].map(item => [item._id, item]))
        );
      }
    } else if (isObject(targetValue) && isObject(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = mergeDeep(Object.assign({}, targetValue), sourceValue);
    } else {
      target[key] = sourceValue;
    }
  });
  return target;
}

// Demo
const obj1 = [{"_id": "63eb2c20fd30492730e203bb","name": "name 01","isActive": true,"locations": [],"code": "888888"},{"_id": "638482b90b6d64eccee23be7","name": "name 02","isActive": true,"locations": [{"primaryContact": {"name": "name 03","designation": "","email": "","phone": "+1 845566 556","isBilling": true},"_id": "638484359f153cecd64212a8"},{"primaryContact": {"name": "name 04","designation": "","email": "","phone": "(000) 000-0000","isBilling": true},"_id": "638484359f153cecd6464789"},{"primaryContact": {"name": "name 05","designation": "","email": "","phone": "(000) 000-0000","isBilling": true},"_id": "638484359f153cecd65843a8"}]}];
const obj2=[{"_id": "63eb2c20fd30492730e203bb","name": "name 01","isActive": true,"locations": [],"code": "888888"},{"_id": "638482b90b6d64eccee23be7","name": "name 02","isActive": true,"locations": [{"primaryContact": {"name": "name 03","designation": "","email": "","phone": "+1 845566 556","isBilling": true},"_id": "638484359f153cecd64212a8"},{"primaryContact": {"name": "name 08","designation": "","email": "","phone": "(000) 000-0000","isBilling": true},"_id": "638484359f153ferg52a8"}]},{"_id": "63eb2c20hijkl920e203bb","name": "name 10","isActive": true,"locations": [],"code": "888888"}];
mergeDeep(obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj1);
```